# How to resolve promise in protractor.config.js

Tags: typescript, protractor, angular-cli

I have added protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter in my config able to generate report but in console i am getting error "Unhanded promise rejection

Answer (score 1):

This error is given you where you have code like this

```
.then(() => console.log('Success')); // second parameter is for rejection function
```

Here I have missed the `reject` function to pass to `then` as the second parameter. So you need to pass it also to pass the compiler. You need to have a code part where you can handle the errors which comes from asynchronous parts of your code.

```
.then(() => console.log('Success'), (err) => console.log(err));
```

For each Promise in your code you need to pass also a logic to run in an error case of your application.

Comment: I have not used then function below is my config file

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const HtmlReporter = require('protractor-angular-screenshot-reporter');
var d = new Date();
var report = d.getDate() + '-' + d.getMonth() + '-' + d.getFullYear() + '-' + d.getHours() + '-' + d.getMinutes() + '-' + d.getSeconds();

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './test/e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome', //Allow execution against one browsers.
    directConnect: true,
  },

Comment: //directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 60000,
    print: function () { }
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'test/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
      baseDirectory: './test/e2e/report/report_' + report,
      takeScreenShotsForSkippedSpecs: true
    }).getJasmine2Reporter());